# How do I get access to domain objects from a Quartz job?

Tags: grails, groovy

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the grails quartz plugin, you can reference domain objects right in your job as easily as you can in Controllers or Services.

```
Book.get(1)

Book.findByTitle("House of Leaves")
```

etc.